# Yii2 Stripe Webhook testing: "[ERROR] Failed to Post"

Tags: yii2, webhooks

I set up a basic Webhook endpoint in a Yii2 controller just to test the connection:

```
class CreditCardController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                     'webhook' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if ($action->id == 'webhook')
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

... I just want to dump the payload and return HTTP 200 (roughly based on an example I followed [here](https://youtu.be/ROBIBNiVPI4))

```
    public function actionWebhook()
    {
        $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
        ob_start();
        var_dump($payload);
        error_log(ob_get_clean(), 4);

        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);
    }
```

I installed the Stripe CLI and forwarded the Webhook to my local test server:

```
stripe listen -f https://testsite.office/credit-card/webhook
```

When I trigger an event that includes something I am listening for:

```
stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded
```

I get this message:

[ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "https://testsite.office/credit-card/webhook": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

If I remove the POST rule for the action and code the URL in a browser, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Joe

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the way your framework is handling the POST request when the Stripe CLI forwards the event. Can you confirm your server receives the request? Does it make it to the controller? You need to provide more detailed debugging information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone slogging along with the same issue (I don't see a lot of Stripe/Yii2 webhook chatter online), here is what worked for me.

I noticed that Yii threw a HeadersAlreadySentException in the Apache error_log.  So I had to had to specify the response format as JSON:

```
return new Response([
    'format' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'statusCode' => 200,
    'statusText' => 'Webhook Handled',
]);
```

Probably not consequential to this problem, but I also changed accessing the payload to the "Yii way":

```
$payload = json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody(), true);
```